# Listar nudos desde base de datos firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Quiero listar desde la base de datos de firebase 2 nudos: tengo un nudo que llamo Restaurante y otro Categorías. En Categorías tengo dos nudos diferentes donde pongo 2 nudos hijos que a su vez tienen hijos. Quiero listar en un `recycleview` los elementos de cada restaurante y no sé cómo hacerlo. Quiero listarlo por su id del restaurante que también lo tengo en mi base de datos Categoría.

Éste es mi código

AdapterCategoria

```
package com.example.joserayo.myrestaurantev3.View;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.joserayo.myrestaurantev3.Model.Categorias;
import com.example.joserayo.myrestaurantev3.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;


public class AdapterCategorias extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCategorias.categorias> {
    private List<Categorias>cate;

    private Context context1;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public  AdapterCategorias(Context context,List<Categorias> categoria){
        context1= context;
        cate=categoria;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public categorias onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_categoria,parent,false);
        categorias categorias=new categorias(view);

        return categorias;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull categorias holder, int position) {
        Categorias categ=cate.get(position);
        holder.nombre.setText(categ.getNombre());
        holder.descripio.setText(categ.getDescripcion());
        holder.precio.setText(categ.getPrecio());
        Picasso.with(context1).load(categ.getUrl()).fit()
                .into(holder.foto);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cate.size();
    }

    public static  class categorias extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView nombre, descripio,precio;
        ImageView foto;
        public categorias(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            nombre=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
            descripio=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.descr);
            precio=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.pre);
            foto=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagenlistar);

        }
    }



}
```

este es mi actividad listar

```
package com.example.joserayo.myrestaurantev3.View;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.joserayo.myrestaurantev3.Model.Categorias;
import com.example.joserayo.myrestaurantev3.Model.CategoriasHolder;
import com.example.joserayo.myrestaurantev3.R;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListarCategorias extends AppCompatActivity  {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    String foodid="";
  RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
List<Categorias>list;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    AdapterCategorias adapter;
    private Query productQuery;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Categorias,CategoriasHolder>  recyclerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_categorias);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myreclicleview);
         recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
         manager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);


        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String idres = bundle.getString("idres");
        Log.d("Idrestau", "" + idres);
            listar(idres);
list=new ArrayList<>();



    }
    private void listar(String idres) {
        productQuery = reference.child("Categorias/bebidas")
                .orderByChild("idRestaurante").equalTo(idres);


        productQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Categorias categorias= data.getValue(Categorias.class);
                    list.add(categorias);
                }
                adapter=new AdapterCategorias(ListarCategorias.this,list);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(ListarCategorias.this,databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });

                Log.d("encontrado",""+idres);

    }
```

base de datos firebase nudo categoria

base de datos de mi restaurante: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que Firebase es una base de datos NoSql , por lo tanto no debes pensar la estructura de la misma de una forma relacional.

Para solucionar tu problema deberias reestructurar tu tabla para que dentro de restaurantes crees otro nudo con la categoria del mismo, de esa forma te quedaria

```
-Restaurante Fusion
      +--Categoria
```

De esta manera podes acceder a los datos del restaurant y los datos de la categoria donde pertenece, sin tener que relacional dos nudos y hacer mas referencias